# Local Storage communication for 2 windows

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I created a small project where I click a Button which opens a new window. This window is requesting information from a server.

The window should now pass the information back to mainpage where the Button is placed.

I tried to work with localStorage and this is what I got until now:

Sender:

```
var fbKey = "test";

localStorage.fb_auth_key = fbKey;

alert(localStorage.fb_auth_key);
```

Receiver:

```
document.getElementById('output').textContent = "" + localStorage.fb_auth_key;
```

The Receiver is refreshing this all the time, but I always get "undefined" - the alert in the sender has the right result.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use cross document messaging:

Sender:

```
window.opener.postMessage("test", "http://example.com")
```

Receive:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
        if(e.origin === "http://example.com/"){
            if(e.data){
                document.getElementById("output").textContent = e.data;
            }
        }
    }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you only set a local variable attribute.

try: window.localStorage.getItem("key")
and: window.localStorage.setItem("key", value)